# ReferenceError: Can't find variable:

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

http://staging1.unep.org/iris-dev/default/Auto/generate-indicator/2adab4ea-352b-450d-b8d1-95d21b3e353b

The webpage above is loading fine on web browsers (Firefox & Chrome) and loads an online spreadsheet and a map. I want to use PhantomJS to capture a screenshot of the map rendered in  `div#chart-or-map`

I have the following code in my `generate_indictor.js` file

```
    var page = require('webpage').create();

    page.open('http://staging1.unep.org/iris-dev/default/auto/generate-indicator/2adab4ea-352b-450d-b8d1-95d21b3e353b', function() {
  // being the actual size of the headless browser
  page.viewportSize = { width: 1440, height: 900 };

  var clipRect = page.evaluate(function(){
    return document.querySelector('#chart-or-map').getBoundingClientRect();
  });

  page.clipRect = {
    top:    clipRect.top,
    left:   clipRect.left,
    width:  clipRect.width,
    height: clipRect.height
  };

  page.render('/tmp/map.png');
  phantom.exit();
});
```

From my console I run `phantomjs generate_indictor.js`  but then I get the following error:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: get_spatial_data

  http://staging1.unep.org/iris-dev/default/auto/generate-indicator/2adab4ea-352b-450d-b8d1-95d21b3e353b:1115 in draw_map
  http://staging1.unep.org/iris-dev/default/auto/generate-indicator/2adab4ea-352b-450d-b8d1-95d21b3e353b:1133
```

When I look at the HTML source code of the page, `get_spatial_data` has been clearly defined as a function.

What I'm I missing?

Comment: Is this ReferenceError actually a problem? Is the screenshot wrong/broken because of it? Please register to the `onConsoleMessage`, `onError`, `onResourceError`, `onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf)). Maybe there are errors.

Comment: @ArtjomB. The screenshot is blank because `get_spatial_data` is used to draw the map. I have registered all the suggested events but nothing is being logged.